# Create search => replacement array by key intersection

Tags: php, arrays, string, intersection

I have this simple PHP code:

```
<?php

    $string = "M - T - A - C - B - N - Z.";

    $arrayOne  = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
    $arrayTwo  = ["D", "E", "F", "G"];


    $length = count($arrayOne);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
        $replacement[$arrayOne[$i]] = $arrayTwo[$i];
    }

    echo strtr($string, $replacement);

?>
```

Here I just use the numerical index from both arrays to create a replacement array, which I can use in `strtr()`.

```
$replacement = [
    "A" => "D",
    "B" => "E",
    "C" => "F",
    "D" => "G",
];
```

Now I want to do the same thing, just only for the values where the two arrays have the same keys.

So if I have:

```
$k_1  = [ 
    "hat" => "M",
    "new" => "A",
    "bad" => "B",
    "hot" => "C",
    "big" => "D"    
];


$k_2  = [
    "new" => "D",
    "bad" => "E",
    "hot" => "F",
    "err" => "K",
    "big" => "G"
];
```

We get the following intersection by keys from the two arrays:

```
[
    "new",
    "bad",
    "hot",
    "big",
]
```

Now I want to use again the values from the first array with these keys as search and the second array values as replacement, e.g.

```
$replacement = [
    "A" => "D",
    "B" => "E",
    "C" => "F",
    "D" => "G",
];
```

How do I need to modify my code now, that it will do it like this?

Answer (score 1):

Start by normalizing the arrays

```
$kk_1=array_intersect($k_1, $k_2);
$kk_2=array_intersect($k_2, $kk_1);
ksort($kk_1);
ksort($kk_2);
$k_1=array_values($kk_1);
$k_2=array_values($kk_2);
```

then continue as before - `$k_1` and `$k_2` will have the correct values and order.

Comment: @lvk I misread your question. But Eugen almost has the solution. You just have to get the intersection from both sides of the array as he did and then just combine it for the replacement, see: https://3v4l.org/buWVa

Comment: In this answer the sorting isn't needed and creating the replacement array can easily be done with `array_combine()`. ^^ See example link above.

Comment: @lvk Since I misread the question and Eugen actually has the solution, just with some not necessary code, I will leave it up to him if he wants to remove the `ksort()` and use `array_combine()` which shortens everything a bit. So you can accept his answer if you want (See: [tour]). (Also your question was good and clear :)

Comment: @Rizier123 As always with my SO answers, I chose clarity above brevity - my impression being, that the sequence of code chosen makes it more clear what is going on then the shorter and more efficient versionwith `array_combine()`.

Comment: Okay, I feel like `array_combine()` is more clear and shorter, but if you don't feel like this :) But sorting the arrays would be still unnecessary, reindexing is necessary with your way, but sorting not.

Comment: @Rizier123 Before the question was edited, it was not at all clear, that the keys would be in the needed order (at least that's how I read it). So the `ksort()` was necessary. Additionally, a `ksort()` on an already sorted array is very fast, so the safety net it gives might outweigh the performance it costs.